# Which value(s) in WHERE CLAUSE LIST are not available in the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to search which value(s) in MY WHERE CLAUSE LIST are not available in the table.

Table name is test

```
Column1
--------------
1
2
3
```

My query : I have a search list 2, 3, 4, 5 and I want to see which all are not in my database. When I query, I should get 4, 5 and NOT 1.

I do not want the list of values which are there in the table and not in where clause list(select * from test where column1 not in (2, 3, 4, 5)

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Can you please tell, if my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

```
  WITH my_list AS
  (SELECT regexp_substr('2,3,4,5', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS search_val
  FROM dual
    CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count('2,3,4,5',',') + 1
  )
SELECT *
FROM my_list
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 'X' FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE YOUR_COLUMN = search_val
  );
```

Let's Convert the comma separated values into a view and then do what's needed.

Comment: I will check and post here later whether it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
SELECT List FROM
(SELECT 2 as List
UNION
SELECT 3
UNION
SELECT 4
UNION
SELECT 5) T
WHERE List NOT IN
      (SELECT Column1 FROM TableName)
```

Comment: my list is this big - (1,4,5,8,9,12,13,14,20,39,43,48,51,54,55,57,61,65,68,75,78,80,81,82,91,92,96,99,102,103,109,112,113,224,227,249,250,251,600,601,604,605,608,609,614,802);
so I will have to add select for each variable, correct ? thanks.

Comment: @libadarsh.so.1.0.1: Yes. I was looking for solution of this type of problem. And this is the only way that worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
 (select 2 as val from dual
  union all 
  select 3 from dual
  union all 
  select 4 from dual
  union all 
  select 5 from dual
  union all 
 )
select * from cte as t1
where not exists 
  ( select * from test as t2 where t1.val = t2.column1)
```

For a large number of values you might better create a temporary table, insert the rows and then use this instead of the common table expression.

Comment: i have thought about creating temporray table, but was looking for a better alternative.
I am thinking whether there is some option to create a set of dynamic rows and then doing the join with the master table.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would do a simple select

```
select *
from test
where column1 in (2, 3, 4, 5)
```

and do the set operation in the host language (Java, C++, Perl, ...).

This seems far simpler than any SQL solution.

Comment: i would like to handle with query alone

Answer (score 0):

Try below Query:

```
 WITH MY_DATA_TABLE AS
(
    SELECT regexp_substr('2,3,4,5', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS MY_DATA_VALUE
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY level <= (length('2,3,4,5') - length(replace('2,3,4,5', ',')))
  )
SELECT *
FROM MY_DATA_TABLE
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 'TRUE' FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE TABLE_FIELD_VALUE = MY_DATA_VALUE
  );
```

Your query with huge data would translate in ORACLE to:

```
 WITH MY_DATA_TABLE AS
(
    SELECT regexp_substr('1,4,5,8,9,12,13,14,20,39,43,48,51,54,55,57,61,65,68,75,78,80,81,82,91,92,96,99,‌​102,103,109,112,113,224,227,249,250,251,600,601,604,605,608,609,614,802', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS MY_DATA_VALUE
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY level <= (length('1,4,5,8,9,12,13,14,20,39,43,48,51,54,55,57,61,65,68,75,78,80,81,82,91,92,96,99,‌​102,103,109,112,113,224,227,249,250,251,600,601,604,605,608,609,614,802') - length(replace('1,4,5,8,9,12,13,14,20,39,43,48,51,54,55,57,61,65,68,75,78,80,81,82,91,92,96,99,‌​102,103,109,112,113,224,227,249,250,251,600,601,604,605,608,609,614,802', ',')))
  )
SELECT *
FROM MY_DATA_TABLE
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 'TRUE' FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE TABLE_FIELD_VALUE = MY_DATA_VALUE
  );
```

Comment: Same as my version. btw, `regexp_count` make the job easier to count the commas.

Comment: @OracleUser: REGEXP_COUNT throws error in query. I guess it can be used only in select clause and not in connect by level (Not sure! Pardon me if wrong!)

Comment: No @Nishanthi it returns a `PLS_INTEGER` value, and can be used anywhere. Available since 11g version. You might have checked lower versions.

Comment: @OracleUser: You are right. I had some copy paste issue and it threw error in the regexp_count part. Hence found an alternative and posted it. Have +1 your answer :)